# populating model through rest api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm currently working on a rails app where I have two model classes, Account and User.  I want to allow users to link their User with account information from other places.

What I want the user to be able to do is, under my edit user form, I have a list displaying the names of all linked accounts, and a text input for them to add more.

All I want them to do is fill in one field (account name) and hit a button, and the back end will hit a restful API for that account name, pull back relevant info, and populate an Account model object, linking to the current user.

For example, from the user page I would like the user to be able to type in their twitter handle, and in the back end I'd look up that twitter account id and associate it with that User in my database.

Where is the right place to have a hook so that I can take an input (twitter handle), fire off a helper method that populates a Account object, and then link that to my current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you were asking but I'll try my best : If your account 'belongs_to' your User model, it would seem logical to use the create or update method (depending on your standard case) of your Accounts controller, to retrieve a JSON with the accounts datas, and that the client parse this answer (with some JS).

Comment: I think I'm heavily over-complicating my rails form and thats the problem.  I was trying to do the addition through the user form (so it was coming off as a update user rather than a create account), but I think that this is the better way.